# Can't find screw on leaky faucet handle

Tags: leak, faucet

[image]One of my bathroom faucet recently started leaking.  If I push it all the way to the back, it starts dripping, if I turn it ccw a bit, then the leaking almost stops.  I'm thinking it may be a washer issue.

I remember buying this faucet from Home Deport about 15 years ago.  However, I don't have the installation guide, I went to HD recently, but couldn't find it.

I checked every part of the knob, but can't find any screw.

I'd really appreciate your help in letting me know how to remove the knob to reveal the stem and washer.  Also appreciate any tips on what may have caused the leak.

Thanks.

Comment: On these I believe you simply pull the handle up and it should slide off the stem.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, thanks.  Any other suggestions?